# Setting page margins on print

Tags: html, css

I have a page that accesses our database and populates a table with data from our database. I had to add a new column to that table recently and it caused some of the spacing to be way off.

There are 9 columns in the table and I have each of them setting their width to 11% of the page:

```
<TD WIDTH=11%>
```

and that makes the table fill the page from left to right (I know, 9 * 11 = 99%, close enough). The problem is that it forces some of the data to be 2 lines. I am required to prinbt in portrait orientation and have most of the data on one line. This is not working now that I added the new column. I believe that if I can have the page print with minimal page margins and then have the table re-size itself into those margins that I would have enough room to make it look the way I want it.

The problem is, how do I make the page have minimal margins and then have the table re-size itself into the full page size?

I have tried a CSS style sheet that looks like

```
@page{
margin-left:1mm;
margin-right:1mm;
}
```

...but that inst doing what I want it to do.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@page{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}`

have you tried this ? Would be nice if you will provide more HTML/CSS code